# How to sign out Firebase user for a specific Authentication Provider

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

In Firebase homepage, in order to log out we call

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

But assume that I've logged in simultaneously with both Facebook and Twitter, how can I logout only for the Facebook Authentication Provider?

Comment: I don't think this is possible: if the two authentication providers are linked to the same account (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) you will signout the user for all authentication providers. To be double checked however! Note that you can unlink an authentication provider from the user account.